# Playlist shortcode, prevent repeat

Tags: playlist

I'm using the WordPress playlist shortcode to present a few audio samples on a given page. For example:

```
[playlist images="false" artists="false" ids="542,543"]
```

The shortcode, by default loops the playlist. The [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Playlist_Shortcode) on the codex doesn't show an option to disable autorepeat/looping of the playlist via a parameter.

I need to disable the looping of the playlist; that is play it only once. I've tried binding to the 'ended' event as suggested on this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152447/audio-playlist-how-to-bind-events-for-track-change-track-end) but I'm not sure if this older post is still valid. The example code won't fire at all.

Any suggestions on how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to bind to the `audio` object's `ended` event. But there is certainly more logic that would need to be added. This is working for me:

```
(function($){

    var customAudio = {

        initialize: function() {
            var self = this;
            // execute logic independently for each playlist in the document
            $('.wp-playlist').each(function(index) {
                // determine the last track in the playlist so that
                // when the last track ends we can pause the audio object
                lastTrack = $(this).find('.wp-playlist-tracks .wp-playlist-item:last a');
                // bind to the audio object's ended event and execute
                // our own ended logic
                $(this).find('audio').on('ended', function() {
                    // pass the audio object and the last track
                    self.ended(this, lastTrack);
                });
            });
        },

        ended : function (audio, lastTrack) {
            // if this audio element is the last track, pause it
            if ( audio.currentSrc === lastTrack.attr('href') ) {
                audio.pause();
            }
        }
    };

    $(function() {
        customAudio.initialize();
    });

}(jQuery));
```